# Garbage Collection in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++, memory-management, garbage-collection

Consider the below:

```
#include <iostream>

public ref class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass() { std::cerr << "TestClass()\n"; }
    ~TestClass() { std::cerr << "~TestClass()\n"; }
};

public ref class TestContainer {
public:
    TestContainer() : m_handle(gcnew TestClass) { }

private:
    TestClass^ m_handle;
};

void createContainer() {
    TestContainer^ tc = gcnew TestContainer();
        // object leaves scope and should be marked for GC(?)
}


int main() {
    createContainer();

    // Manually collect.
    System::GC::Collect();
    System::GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // ... do other stuff

    return 0;
}
```

My output is simply:
    TestClass()

I never get ~TestClass().  This is a simplification of an issue I am having in production code, where a list of handles is being cleared and repopulated multiple times, and the handle destructors are never being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Sincerely,
Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~TestClass()
```

declares a Dispose function.

```
!TestClass()
```

would declare a finaliser (the equivalent of C#'s `~TestClass`) which gets called on a gc collection (although that's not guaranteed).

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize this was the case.

Comment: And I think C++/CLI will make sure TestClass implements IDispose when you add ~TestClass(), so other .NET languages will understand it.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `~TestClass()` means different things in C# and C++, but Dispose functions really are the closest parallel to a C++ destructor.